# Rails: How to start thin server in ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, thin

I am trying to start thin serve on https protocol but getting below error.

Below is the command that i am using for thin server to start thin server in https

```
E:\demo1>thin start --ssl --ssl-verify --ssl-key-file E:/demo1/server.key --ssl-cert-file E:/demo1/server.crt
```

Below is the error that i am getting.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/runner.
rb:147:in `parse!': invalid option: --ssl-verify (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib
/thin/runner.rb:50:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/bin
/thin:6:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/bin
/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by removing  --ssl-verify from command.

```
thin start -p 3001 --ssl --ssl-key-file E:/demo1/server.key --ssl-cert-file E:/demo1/server.crt
```